# CAST, My query don't give correct values.

Tags: replace, casting

I'm merging 2 fields into one value. I'm also replacing dots with commas with the below query.

REPLACE(CAST(testmin as varchar)+'-'+ CAST(testmax as varchar), '.', ',') AS Testvalue

This works a a charm as long as testmin isn't zero. But when it's zero that's the result I get.

As example I have

testmin 0,00
testmax 100

With the above query the the query returns 0. 
If I change testmin to 1 then the query returns the correct value 1-100.

Any ideas on why it is like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) instead of '+' ?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick answer. How exactly? I think I tried that before but didn't get it to work. Worth to know is that I'm not that experiences with sql...

Comment: `REPLACE(CONCAT(CAST(testmin as varchar),'-',CAST(testmax as varchar)), '.', ',') AS Testvalue` ?

Comment: I get this error mesage: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: I do not know SQL server very well but which version are you using ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx. This function seems to appear in 2014 version.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. 
 
I might add that I'm using a add on for Excel where I make the queries and the result is then presented in Excel.

Comment: Never used it. You should break down your query in small part and see what is the result : `SELECT CAST(0 as varchar);` then `SELECT (CAST(0 as varchar)+'-') as test` .. to determine where is the error.

Comment: I don't know if it could work but there is a STR function which seems to do the job of the cast you are doing : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527(v=sql.105).aspx